# Way to automate tasks in a custom terminal emulator program?

Tags: emulator, avaya

I work with Avaya Site Administrator, telephony software. ASA has an emulator mode (513) that you enter to execute custom commands (I assume this is basically entering a specialized shell).

I am wondering how I can pipe commands to another shell/emulator from Bash and capture the output to a file. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Regarding ASA/SAT in particular, you might want to do a little bit of research on OSSI -- it's what other management apps and scripts use to communicate with CM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explore the Expect programing language.

[Exploring Expect](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565920903) is the title of the O'Reilly book for doing just that.

"Written by the author of Expect, this is the first book to explain how this part of the UNIX toolbox can be used to automate Telnet, FTP, passwd, rlogin, and hundreds of other interactive applications. Based on Tcl (Tool Command Language), Expect lets you automate interactive applications that have previously been extremely difficult to handle with any scripting language."

Yes, it's 16 years old, here is the page for the language now http://expect.sourceforge.net/ with other docs, etc.

Comment: The autoexpect is also great for helping build an expect script while watching you do the task/once. http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/autoexpect1.html

Comment: I was looking for something that would be in the default Solaris/Linux install. The red tape for installing aftermarket software on a server is horrendous... But thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I had just assumed it was in the default install, but I guess not. I would expect that the political is the only issues, as you can get packages for most things. Of course, political is often the hard thing.